# ggplot2 plotly faceted chart colors in legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a ggplot2 graph that is then driving a plotly chart.  I am using the stock diamonds data set and am getting some wonkyness in the legends.  I want the legend to ONLY show colorizing for the colors.  It appears to be trying to take each clarity from each facet and merge into the legend.

How can I get the legend to only show the colors of the the clarities once?  Note: I tried removing size already :)

Below is the code and image of what is produced.

```
d = diamonds %>% sample_frac(.01)    
p = d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = depth, color = clarity)) +
  facet_wrap(~cut) 
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it was fix, but I have seen the same problem on SO with facet_grid()

Comment: Try turning off the size legend: `ggplotly(p + scale_size(guide="none"))`

Comment: Nope, best I can figure is to turn off legends for each trace that gets generated and then render: https://plot.ly/ggplot2/user-guide/#modify-ggplot2-figure biggest issue beyond that is what the calls are after plotly_build to render the figure locally without pushing to my account.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am going down the route of turning off all trace legends (except 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in the plotly rendering of the graphic, which has been resolved in the latest version of plotly.  The solution is to terminate your R session, reinstall your plotly packages and then pull in the updated library.